# Fetching parent and child value from a nested json in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, checkbox, nested

I'm very much new to angularjs so I'm facing this issue where i have a nested json, and i am using the parent value as a header and the values of the child as checkboxes. Now, when I want to retrieve the value of those checkboxes which have been ticked, i want it in the format of {**parent_name:child_name**} stored in an array.

I'm using the following sample data taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4192322/gloria) thread.

Data:

```
parents : [{
    name: 'George',
    age: 44,
    children: [{
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 16, 
        isChecked: 'true'
    },{
        name: 'Amy',
        age: 13, 
        isChecked: 'false'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Jimmy',
    age: 38,
    children: [{
        name: 'Max',
        age: 7, 
        isChecked: 'false'              
    },{
        name: 'Lily',
        age: 5, 
        isChecked: 'false'
    },{
        name: 'Kim',
        age: 4, 
        isChecked: 'true'
    }]
}]
```

And, my current output
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HFK6.jpg)

My HTML code is

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="parent in parents ">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>{{parent.name}}</label>
  <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="child.isChecked=='true'"> {{child.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Now, in reference to the image, I want to have **{George:Jack}** and **{Jimmy:Kim}** in an array, but i can't find a way to achieve that.

**EDIT :** I forgot to mention another important point, some checkboxes will be pre-selected. As per the data, checkbox for Jack and Kim will already be ticked on-load. I have to fetch the value for the pre-selected values as well as any newly checked checkboxes.

My Plunker code is [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CvqqC8zPgm9DVvX5VPS?p=preview)

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution modifies your original JSON object.

If for some reasons, you have to keep the original JSON object, you should do a copy of it and store it in the controller scope (Angular has functions to do it).
The idea is to add a `isChecked` attribute in the original JSON object which will be values to false by default and that will be set to true when the checkbox is selected or false when the checkbox is unselected.
That is possible by using the `ng-model` directive which binds here a html input to a variable in JS side.

Here is the plunker : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/EzDp3mMtlnH3t4bIz8e6?p=preview with Angular js 1.5.

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  $scope.parents = [{
    name: 'George',
    age: 44,
    children: [{
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 16,
        isChecked: true;
    },{
        name: 'Amy',
        age: 13
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Jimmy',
    age: 38,
    children: [{
        name: 'Max',
        age: 7              
    },{
        name: 'Lily',
        age: 5
    },{
        name: 'Kim',
        age: 4,
        isChecked: true;
    }]
}]


$scope.submit= function(){

   var results = [];
   for (var i=0; i< $scope.parents.length; i++){

      var parent = $scope.parents[i];
        for (var j=0; j< parent.children.length; j++){

            var child =  parent.children[j];

            if (child.isChecked){
                results.push(parent.name +":"+ child.name);
            }
        }
   }

   //display info
   for ( i=0; i< results.length; i++){
    console.log(results[i]) ;
   }

}

});
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="parent in parents ">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>{{parent.name}}</label>
       <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
          <label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="child.isChecked=='true'" ng-model="child.isChecked">  
           {{child.name}}</label>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
   <button type="button" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-success width-80px">Submit</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, but I missed to mention a really important point, please have a look at my re-edited question.

Comment: Just set the `isChecked` property to `true` for desired children. You can do that from the original JSON object with a function or have a JSON object with values already set.  I directly modified the JSON to go faster. I updated my answer and the plunkr

Comment: I have set the `isChecked` property for all the children to their respective values and then tried executing your code but couldn't get it working. It is giving me the values of all the checkboxes, irrespective of whether any selection has been done or not. Here is the plunker [code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CvqqC8zPgm9DVvX5VPS?p=preview)

Comment: sorry, it is boolean value, it should not be between quotes otherwise it is interepreted as a string and not a boolean value.  I updated your plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/2zQWAk6YybCpzqNKgUkR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive, you can only mark the checkbox as checked if the expression (here `child.checked=='true'`) is truthy. However, it doesn't affect the value of your variable `child.checked`.

I recommand you to use instead the [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive which will bind the value of your checkbox with `child.checked` (or any other variable).

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="parent in parents ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{parent.name}}</label>
  <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child.checked">{{child.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Since `child.checked` is not defined at the begining, it will be falsy so the checkbox won't be checked. You can change this behaviour by setting it to `true`.

Then, to create an array of your results, you can do something like this:

```
var results = [];
parents.forEach(function (parent) {
  parent.children.forEach(function (child) {
    if (child.checked) {
      var couple = {};
      couple[parent.name] = child.name;
      results.push(couple);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I missed to mention a really important point, please have a look at my re-edited question.